# Python Pandas mlutiplication witihin one column base on a condition in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I am trying to multiply quantity defined as column ['TRGQTY'] within different rows in my DataFrame based on the condition defined for other columns. I want to take the ['TRGQTY'] where ['SUBPACKNR'] is not blank and multiply it with ['TRGQTY'] of all rows that containe in column ['BALICI_INSTRUKCE'] == 'PV%+1'(this column express the level -> PV2 = level 2 or PV3 = level 3).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DISPO': ['580', '580', '580','580', '580', '580'],
                   'MATNR_FERT': ['04440210721VL', '04440210721VL', '04440210721VL','04440210721VL', '04440210721VL', '04440210721VL'],
                   'STATUS_FERT': ['40', '40', '40','40', '40', '40'],
                   'PACKNR': ['GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW','GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW'],
                   'BALICI_INSTRUKCE': ['PV2', 'PV1', 'PV2','PV1', 'PV1', 'PV2'], 'ČÍSLO_MATERIÁLU': ['6000146128', '6000129044', '6099504147','6000100412', '', '04440210721VL'],
                   'SUBPACKNR': ['', '', '','', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', ''],
                   'TRGQTY': ['1', '1', '1','1', '60', '20'],
                   'BASEUNIT': ['ST', 'ST', 'ST','ST', 'ST', 'ST'] })

data_csv = [[DISPO, MATNR_FERT, STATUS_FERT, PACKNR, BALICI_INSTRUKCE, ČÍSLO_MATERIÁLU, SUBPACKNR, TRGQTY, BASEUNIT], [580, 04440210721VL, 40 ,GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW, PV2, 6000146128, 1, ST], [580, 04440210721VL, 40, GgZK{OS27kYc{uX3IyhQNW, PV1, 6000129044, 1, ST], [580, 04440210721VL, 40, GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW, PV2, 6099504147, 1, ST], [580, 04440210721VL, 40, GgZK{OS27kYc{uX3IyhQNW, PV1, 6000100412, 1, ST], [580, 04440210721VL, 40, GgZK{OS27kYc{uX3IyhQNW, PV1, GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW, 60, ST], [580, 04440210721VL, 40, GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW, PV2, 04440210721VL, 20, ST]]
```

[image]

This is my code, but the multiplication does not work correctly.

```
df_cislodilu = [data_csv]

nasobky = {}


for i in pd.unique(df_cislodilu['MATNR_FERT']):
    df_subset = df_cislodilu[df_cislodilu['MATNR_FERT'] == i]
    multiplicator = df_subset[~df_subset['SUBPACKNR'].isna()] #nefunguje pro výběr násobku
    level = df_subset[df_subset['BALICI_INSTRUKCE'] == 'PV2'] # or 'PV%'+1
    final = level['TRGQTY'].prod()
    nasobky[i] = df_subset['TRGQTY'] * final
    
    nasobky = pd.DataFrame(nasobky)



print(nasobky)
```

This is the result of this code
[image]

This is what I need:
[image]

Sourcecode for more 'MATNR_FERT':

df = pd.DataFrame({
'DISPO': ['580', '580', '580', '580', '580', '580', '580', '580', '580', '580', '580', '580'],
'MATNR_FERT': ['04440210721VL', '04440210721VL', '04440210721VL', '04440210721VL', '04440210721VL', '04440210721VL', '04440210722A5', '04440210722A5', '04440210722A5', '04440210722A5', '04440210722A5', '04440210722A5'],
'STATUS_FERT': ['40', '40', '40', '40', '40', '40', '40', '40', '40', '40', '40', '40'],
'PACKNR': ['GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNM', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNM', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNM', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNM', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNM', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNM'],
'BALICI_INSTRUKCE': ['PV2', 'PV1', 'PV2', 'PV1', 'PV1', 'PV2', 'PV2', 'PV1', 'PV2', 'PV1', 'PV1', 'PV2'],
'ČÍSLO_MATERIÁLU': ['6000146128', '6000129044', '6099504147', '6000100412', '', '04440210721VL', '6000146128', '6000129044', '6099504147', '6000100412', '', '04440210721VL'],
'SUBPACKNR': ['', '', '', '', 'GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW}', '', '', '', '', '', 'GgZK{OS27jcWY}lueMkCeW', ''],
'TRGQTY': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '60', '20', '1', '1', '1', '1', '60', '20'],
'BASEUNIT': ['ST', 'ST', 'ST', 'ST', 'ST', 'ST', 'ST', 'ST', 'ST', 'ST', 'ST', 'ST']
})

Code for multiplication:

```
enter code here
# ensure having numeric data
df['TRGQTY'] = df['TRGQTY'].astype(int)
#sort values by ['part_number']
df = df.sort_values(by=['part_number'])
#create subset table and operate within each small subset table with same PART_NUMBER
df = df['part_number'].unique()
# is BALICI_INSTRUKCE PV1?
m1 = df['BALICI_INSTRUKCE'].eq('PV1')
# is BALICI_INSTRUKCE PV2/PV3/PV4?
m2 = df['BALICI_INSTRUKCE'].eq('PV2')
m3 = df['BALICI_INSTRUKCE'].eq('PV3')
m4 = df['BALICI_INSTRUKCE'].eq('PV4')
# is SUBPACKNR not an empty string?
m5 = df['SUBPACKNR'].ne('')
# if m1 and m3 are True, get the first value
ref = df.loc[m1&m5, 'TRGQTY'].iloc[0] # 60
# multiply the PV2 by the reference
df.loc[m2|m3|m4, 'TRGQTY'] *= ref
print(df)
```

Comment: please don't use images of data, provide a fully reproducible input and the matching expected output

Comment: agree with @mozway give us a representative input dataframe (made up data, sanitized data ...) and a piece of python that is standalone and we can use to reproduce. Pictures of data are useless : we need the actual data to help you. And of course we have no clue of what is `C:/Users/kbm2bj/Documents/DA_2022_Python/Machine Learning/course/přehození_sloupců.csv"`

Comment: This is the table I want to transform with python:
DISPO MATNR_FERT STATUS_FERT PACKNR BALICI_INSTRUKCE ČÍSLO_MATERIÁLU SUBPACKNR TRGQTY BASEUNIT
580 04440210721VL 40 GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW PV2 6000146128   1 ST
580 04440210721VL 40 GgZK{OS27kYc{uX3IyhQNW PV1 6000129044   1 ST
580 04440210721VL 40 GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW PV2 6099504147   1 ST
580 04440210721VL 40 GgZK{OS27kYc{uX3IyhQNW PV1 6000100412   1 ST
580 04440210721VL 40 GgZK{OS27kYc{uX3IyhQNW PV1   GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW 60 ST
580 04440210721VL 40 GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW PV2 04440210721VL   20 ST

Comment: please [edit] the question with this data, also make sure that you can reproduce the issue from thee data that you post here (if you can't we also won't be able to)

Comment: This is my current code:
import pandas as pd
df_cislodilu = pd.read_csv("data.csv", encoding='utf-8')
nasobky = {}
for i in pd.unique(df_cislodilu['MATNR_FERT']):
    df_subset = df_cislodilu[df_cislodilu['MATNR_FERT'] == i]
    multiplicator = df_subset[~df_subset['SUBPACKNR'].isna()]
    level = df_subset[df_subset['BALICI_INSTRUKCE'] == 'PV2'] # or 'PV%'+1
    final = level['TRGQTY'].prod()
    nasobky[i] = df_subset['TRGQTY'] * final
    nasobky = pd.DataFrame(nasobky)
print(nasobky)

Comment: You should really read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @Michaela is there only one row with non-null SUBPACKNR?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want:

```
# ensure having numeric data
df['TRGQTY'] = df['TRGQTY'].astype(int)

# is BALICI_INSTRUKCE PV1?
m1 = df['BALICI_INSTRUKCE'].eq('PV1')
# is BALICI_INSTRUKCE PV2?
m2 = df['BALICI_INSTRUKCE'].eq('PV2')
# is SUBPACKNR not an empty string?
m3 = df['SUBPACKNR'].ne('')

# if m1 and m3 are True, get the first value
ref = df.loc[m1&m3, 'TRGQTY'].iloc[0] # 60

# multiply the PV2 by the reference
df.loc[m2, 'TRGQTY'] *= ref
```

Output:

```
  DISPO     MATNR_FERT STATUS_FERT                  PACKNR BALICI_INSTRUKCE ČÍSLO_MATERIÁLU               SUBPACKNR  TRGQTY BASEUNIT
0   580  04440210721VL          40  GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW              PV2      6000146128                              60       ST
1   580  04440210721VL          40  GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW              PV1      6000129044                               1       ST
2   580  04440210721VL          40  GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW              PV2      6099504147                              60       ST
3   580  04440210721VL          40  GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW              PV1      6000100412                               1       ST
4   580  04440210721VL          40  GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW              PV1                  GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW      60       ST
5   580  04440210721VL          40  GgZK{OS27kYc{uX22fOQNW              PV2   04440210721VL                            1200       ST
```

Comment: @Michaela it is possible to simplify the code (if you have only PV1/PV2, then only one mask of m1/m2 is needed), but I preferred to keep it explicit

Comment: Dear @mozway I am trying to perform the same multiplication with more 'MATNR_FERT' values (please see source code and python code edited in question above). I want to sort values with same 'MATNR_FERT' and perform multiplication only on subsets with same 'MATNR_FERT' in whole df. After sorting the values the multiplication is not working unfortunately.